odftoolkit ODT apply style to table row to not allow breaking across pages
I am trying to manipulate/generate an OpenOffice Writer document (ODT) using Simple API from ODFToolkit. We have a table that is filled dynamically with N rows. It may split across multiple pages and that's okay. But we have the requirement that its rows should NOT split across pages - and whenever that happens, the row that splits should move to the next page and start from there.
When using the graphical UI in LibreOffice, we accomplish the above requirement by right clicking on the table, choosing Properties (that opens the Table Properties dialog box), going to Text Flow (second tab) and unchecking the option "Allow row to break across pages and columns"

We are trying to do this programmatically and fail.
The exact Maven dependency I am using is (the reason we didn't go any higher is the fact that versions higher than this seem to require Java > 1.7 while we got stuck on Java 7):
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.odftoolkit</groupId>
            <artifactId>simple-odf</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.2-incubating</version>
            <classifier>jar-with-dependencies</classifier>
        </dependency>

I have created a sample test code that could be used as a playground. TL;DR I seem to have found something that kind-ishly works, I don't know how reliably, but it's already something.
What we were trying to do is:

to rely on the supposition that each new row should inherit the style of the previous row and, anyway, inherit the style attributes of the parent table
to apply the "may-break-between-rows" style attribute to the table, judging from the way this attribute seems to be a "parent" of the style we need (something that would mean "row" may break between pages) (which seems to not be the case).

From the saved document (I am unzipping it, as ODT files are zipped archives), by examining content.xml, I concluded that there is another attribute called fo:keep-together with the values of AUTO and ALWAYS that also seems to play part in the styles we want to achieve.
Take into account that the document we are opening already contains a table with the name "Table2", and automatic style named "Table2.1" seems to already exist, that contains the keep-together attribute, probably because we have created and saved the original test ODT with the above attribute already "unchecked".
The code that was not working:
InputStream is = OdftoolkittoolTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.odt");
TextDocument textDocument = TextDocument.loadDocument(is);

Table tbl = textDocument.getTableByName("Table2");
OdfStyle odfStyle = tbl.getStyleHandler().getStyleElementForWrite();

// this indeed sets the "allow table to break between pages", 
// but not the "allow row to break between pages" attribute
StyleMayBreakBetweenRowsAttribute attr =
    new StyleMayBreakBetweenRowsAttribute(textDocument.getFileDom(OdfSchemaDocument.OdfXMLFile.CONTENT));
attr.setBooleanValue(true);
odfStyle.setAttributeNode(attr);

// append a single row - once we do this, and inspect the resulting document
// the "allow row to break between pages" shows as "checked" (albeit with a "minus" sign over it - 
// who knows what that means..)
tbl.appendRow();

// try to re-apply the "keep together" style on all rows - just in case this works
// (it doesn't work)
for (Row r : tbl.getRowList()) {
    FoKeepTogetherAttribute attr2 = new FoKeepTogetherAttribute(textDocument.getFileDom(OdfSchemaDocument.OdfXMLFile.CONTENT));
    attr2.setEnumValue(FoKeepTogetherAttribute.Value.ALWAYS);
    r.getOdfElement().setOdfAttribute(attr2);
}

File targetFile = new File("c:\\temp\\lala.odt");
textDocument.save(targetFile);


there's also this question/answer which is also helpful. it shows how to iterate (and possible append to) through existing styles.
Finally the right way to do this is (as I gather) to not apply the style attributes directly to the elements (like table-row), but to have them within a style:style element, and then reference this style from the elements you want this style to apply to.
So something that actually works is as follows:
// remember that there is already a "Table2" in the document that we open
// and it has a style "Table2.1" that contains the "keep-together" property
// as we set it using the Table properties UI dialog box
// practically the below code sets "keep together" attribute to "always" 
// for all existing rows
for (Row r : tbl.getRowList()) {
    applyStyleNameAttributeToRow(r, "Table2.1");
}

...

private Row applyStyleNameAttributeToRow(Row r, String styleName) throws Exception {
    OdfFileDom parentDom = r.getOwnerDocument().getContentDom();
    r.getOdfElement().setStyleName(styleName);
    return r;
}  

